# Users id , C program

Tags: permissions

so I have this simple C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("\nreal uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("\neffective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
}
```

I compile it:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ gcc -o uid_demo uid_demo.c
```

I Look at the permissions:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ ls -l uid_demo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 8512 set 17 11:30 uid_demo
```

and run it:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ ./uid_demo

real uid: 1000

effective uid: 1000
```

Everything all right, I continue:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ sudo chown root:root uid_demo
user@user:~/Desktop$ ls -l uid_demo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8512 set 17 11:30 uid_demo
```

And

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ sudo chmod u+s uid_demo
user@user:~/Desktop$ ls -l uid_demo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 8512 set 17 11:30 uid_demo
```

Here comes the problem:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ ./uid_demo

real uid: 1000

effective uid: 1000
```

I expected to see  **real uid: 1000** and **effective uid: 0**

What am I missing?

Ah and of course:

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ id user
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),121(lpadmin),131(sambashare)
```

Comment: This doesn't belong here, but rather on https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Is the filesystem on which the executable is located mounted with the `nosuid` option by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver how can I see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *may* be the result of having set the `nosuid` mount option on the filesystem where the executable is located. To illustrate, given

```
$ cat uid_demo.c 
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){
    printf("\nreal uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("\neffective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
}
```

then

```
$ gcc -o uid_demo uid_demo.c 
$ sudo chown root:root uid_demo
$ sudo chmod u+s uid_demo
$ ls -l uid_demo
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 8512 Sep 17 07:53 uid_demo
$ 
$ ./uid_demo 

real uid: 1000

effective uid: 0
```

works as expected; however when remounted as `nosuid`, the `suid` bit is still present but is ignored:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,nosuid /home
$ ls -l uid_demo
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 8512 Sep 17 07:53 uid_demo
$ 
$ ./uid_demo 

real uid: 1000

effective uid: 1000
```

---

Provided you know the mountpoint where the file is located, you can see its filesystem mount options by grepping the output of the `mount` command e.g.

```
$ mount | grep /home
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this might be it, could you tell me how to unset the **nosuid** mount option?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this Unix.SE Q&A [setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74527/215641)

> bash detects that it has been started SUID root (UID!=EUID) and uses its root power to throw this power away, resetting EUID to UID

More details in [the linked answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74538/215641)